# jQuery Select HTML Option from Output String of Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a loop building an option set that I fill up an empty  node with using jQuery.

i.e;

```
var optList = function(){
    var list;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        list += '<option>'+i+'</option';
    }
    return optList;
}
$('#mySelect').html(optList());
```

My question is, given my output string from `optList` is there a way of having adding `"selected"` to a predetermined value? like: `<option selected>4</option>` using my string?  I'm asking because **I build my optList BEFORE I am aware of what that predetermined value will be**.

Comment: can set value (selected) any time using `$('#mySelect').val(someValue)`. Setting value of `<select>` itself is same as setting `selected` on the option tag

Comment: There's no need to add it to the string. Just add it to the element after you convert the string to elements, and once you know the selected value.

Comment: Amazing that didn't even cross my mind.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return the function, you have to return the list

```
var optList = function(selected_value){
    var list;
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        var selected = i == selected ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
        list += '<option value="+i+" '+selected+'>'+i+'</option';
    }
    return list;
}

$('#mySelect').html(optList(4));
```

Or you could use what you have and just do

```
$('#mySelect').html(optList()).val(4);
```

Comment: You are correct, This was just for an example, but I will fix it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @HowardZoopaloopa - good for you, I've updated the answer with a solution for setting the selected option